# .net razor make multiline label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following label:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, "text1 / text2", null)
```

I want to move `text2` on new line.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, "text1 /\r\n text2", null)
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, "text1 /<br/> text2", null)
```

didn't help me.

Is there way to do that?

Comment: Try this => `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, Html.Raw("text1 /<br/> text2"), null)`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible using the tag helpers:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, "text1 / <br />text2", null).ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as the Raw keyword will allow you to embed html:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data, "text1 /<br/> text2", null))
```

Comment: since you are using razor pages is there something that is prohibiting you from using the tag helpers for example <label asp-for=""> ......</label>

Comment: I would like to do that with using tag helpers, but if there is no ways then will do with usual HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextAreaFor and set a readonly property to it:

```
<%=Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Data,   new { rows="1", style = "border: 0 none white; background-color:#EEF3FB; color: #424242; width:280px; margin:3px;", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled", })%>
```

[Got it from here](http://maheshde.blogspot.com/2011/10/aspnet-mvc-how-to-implement-multiline.html)